# Kelp GUI error while running in browser

Tags: kelp

How can I run Kelp GUI which is in kelp/gui/web? I was able to build Frontend code but when I run it in browser it shows this error:

```
browser.js:174     POST http://34.192.109.151:3006/api/v1/fetchKelpErrors 404 (Not Found Allowed)
(anonymous) @ browser.js:174
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ browser.js:172
e.fetch @ browser.js:210
value @ fetchKelpErrors.js:4
setInterval (async)
value @ App.js:61
su @ react-dom.production.min.js:5161
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:6408
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:309
Ho @ react-dom.production.min.js:2816
Ss @ react-dom.production.min.js:6204
cs @ react-dom.production.min.js:5895
is @ react-dom.production.min.js:5678
qs @ react-dom.production.min.js:7086
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:7181
fs @ react-dom.production.min.js:5931
Qs @ react-dom.production.min.js:7180
t.render @ react-dom.production.min.js:7363
509 @ index.js:8
f @ (index):1
261 @ kelp-symbol.svg:1
f @ (index):1
a @ (index):1
e @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ main.687d85a6.chunk.js:1
VM357:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<html>
<h"... is not valid JSON
```

This means the backend, which is written in go language, located in kelp/gui/backend, is not running and when I tried to run it says no binary. I created a binary and ran it and then I got this error:

```
./main: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./main: line 1: `!<arch>'
```

and when I run main.go in root it shows this

```
version information not included, please build using the build script (scripts/build.sh)
```

Any leads? How can I run Kelp GUI and its backend in a web browser?